# Bevel tool not working on cylinder

Tags: bevel

[image: Weird]

hi, i'm trying to make a bullet shaped object to look like bolts on a wall but for some reason the bevel tool is being weird with the loop i selected on the cylinder

Comment: can you show us how your topology looks like before you want to use bevel?

Comment: Three things to take into account: normals, object size, and topology (duplicated vertices and stuff like that)

Answer (score 1):

instead of selecting all vertices, just select the top vertices, and you will get:

[image]